# Trying to copy linux blog locally with XAMPP - php fatal error

Tags: php, xampp

I have a WP blog running on a linux machine.

I need to run it locally on XAMPP on Windows 10.

I copied locally the Wordpress blog files to C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw
I the imported the database and assigned privileges according to the wp-config.

I then changed the URL in `wp_options` -> `siteurl` and `home` to http://localhost/mtw

I am getting the following error on screen:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\widgets.php:1261 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\widgets.php(1261): array_merge(wp_inactive_widgets: Array, blog_right_sidebar: Array) #1 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\widgets.php(1216): retrieve_widgets(true) #2 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(289): _wp_sidebars_changed('mtwtheme') #3 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #4 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #5 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\theme.php(2977): do_action('after_switch_th...', 'mtwtheme', Object(WP_Theme)) #6 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(287): check_theme_switched('') #7 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #8 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #9 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-settings.php(540): do_action('init') #10 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-config.php(100): require_once('C:\\xampp2\\htdoc...') #11 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\\xampp2\\htdoc...') #12 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-admin\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\\xampp2\\htdoc...') #13 C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-admin\index.php(10): require_once('C:\\xampp2\\htdoc...') #14 {main} thrown in C:\xampp2\htdocs\mtw\wp-includes\widgets.php on line 1261
There has been a critical error on your website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions.

Learn more about debugging in WordPress.
```

And in the Apache error log:

```
[Tue Feb 01 16:26:37.958522 2022] [php:error] [pid 15376:tid 1848] [client ::1:52929] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: array_merge() does not accept unknown named parameters in C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\widgets.php:1261\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\widgets.php(1261): array_merge(wp_inactive_widgets: Array, blog_right_sidebar: Array)\n#1 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\widgets.php(1216): retrieve_widgets(true)\n#2 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php(289): _wp_sidebars_changed('mtwtheme')\n#3 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#4 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#5 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\theme.php(2977): do_action('after_switch_th...', 'mtwtheme', Object(WP_Theme))\n#6 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php(287): check_theme_switched('')\n#7 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\class-wp-hook.php(311): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array)\n#8 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)\n#9 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-settings.php(540): do_action('init')\n#10 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-config.php(100): require_once('C:\\\\xampp2\\\\htdoc...')\n#11 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\\\\xampp2\\\\htdoc...')\n#12 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-admin\\admin.php(34): require_once('C:\\\\xampp2\\\\htdoc...')\n#13 C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-admin\\index.php(10): require_once('C:\\\\xampp2\\\\htdoc...')\n#14 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp2\\htdocs\\mtw\\wp-includes\\widgets.php on line 1261
```

I tried to troubleshoot that. Removed the database, re-imported, etc. But always the same error.

Can anybody please help?

Comment: When you move a WP site you not only have to change the options but also do a search/replace on the database itself to replace the old URL with the new one. That said, I'm not sure what's going on here - it could be a plugin or theme causing the issue, or something in the XAMPP configuration itself. You might want to try something like the free program Local (https://localwp.com/) instead of XAMPP just to get around all the potential configuration issues, unless you're set on XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Wordpress had an old version. XAMPP had PHP 8. Incompatible.
I uninstalled XAMPP and reinstalled an older version with PHP 7.4.

now it's working fine